# Any way to monitor all GET requests by an application on android

Tags: java, android, proxy, monitoring

So i want monitor an application and see all the requests that are being sent out from the application to the server and if possible all the responses too,(kind of like a box around the application) is there any way to do it?
Also is there any local proxy server for android like charles proxy? if not can anyone tell me how to go about creating one.

Comment: why dont you create some sort of database that logs all the get requests from the android phone and then you can create a web page that well display all the logs.

Comment: @Jared That's what i want to do, but how do i log the request's

Answer (score 1):

If you can load it on the emulator you can use something like Wireshark to see the requests made. The emulator also used to have an http proxy option but it hasn't worked in a long time.

Comment: No that's not really what i am looking for, all the requests need to be monitored on the device actually i am trying to write an app for this.

Comment: In that case it's probably only possible on a rooted phone. There is for example [Shark](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&feature=search_result) which uses the underlying Linux OS to capture TCP traffic.

Comment: Yes i need it for a rooted phone, I saw the tcp dump method but that is a bit complex since you need a computer to analyze the captured data, and the captured, is too much, i was thinking of starting a local proxy server and the routing the traffic through that server while logging the data